# How to completely hide the dockedItems toolbar

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm able to hide items among the dockedItems of a TabPanel, but am wanting to temporarily hide the entire dock, because the toolbar itself still takes up space and the rest of the content does not fill the screen.

So far, I do like so:

```
myApp.views.productList.dockedItems.items[0].removeAll(true);
myApp.views.productList.doComponentLayout();
```

Alternatively:

```
myApp.views.productList.getComponent('search').removeAll(true);
myApp.views.productList.doComponentLayout();
```

But neither removes the dockedItems toolbar itself.

I've even tried to give the dockedItems individually and collectively an `id:` to remove the whole component, but without luck. I've also tried moving the toolbar in question out from the docked items and into the `items:` property of the containing panel, but this breaks other things in my app that I'd rather not change at present.

Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to temporally remove tabBar from a tabPanel. I was able to accomplish this through giving and id to my tabBar and then using removeDocked and addDocked methods. I'm new to sencha-touch so most likely there is a better way of doing this

The code below removes tabBar from tabPanel and then adds it back again.

```
Ext.setup({

onReady: function() {

    var tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({

        ui        : 'dark',
        sortable  : true,
        tabBar:{
            id: 'tabPanelTabBar'
        },
        items: [
            {title: 'Tab 1',html : '1',cls  : 'card1'},
            {title: 'Tab 2',html : '2',cls  : 'card2'},
            {title: 'Tab 3',html : '3',cls  : 'card3'}
        ]
    });

    var paneltest = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        dockedItems:[
            {

                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Disable TabBar',
                scope: this,
                hasDisabled: false,
                handler: function(btn) {

                    console.log(btn);
                    if (btn.hasDisabled) {

                        tabpanel.addDocked(Ext.getCmp('tabPanelTabBar'), 0);

                        btn.hasDisabled = false;
                        btn.setText('Disable TabBar');
                    } else {

                        tabpanel.removeDocked(Ext.getCmp('tabPanelTabBar'), false)

                        btn.hasDisabled = true;
                        btn.setText('Enable TabBar');
                    }
                }}
        ],
        items:[tabpanel]
    });
    paneltest.show()
}
```

})

Comment: That did it! Mine was actually for removing the dockedItems of a sub-tabPanel that had no tabBar set, but this worked. The method I was needing to use was "removeDocked" as you have shown. Thanks!

Comment: Note that searching the Sencha Touch API docs does not return anything for this method! ... But upon going to the Ext.Panel documentation, it is actually listed.

Answer (score 0):

в dockedItems добавить button, которая будет обращаться к элементу panel.dockedItems и изменять/скрывать сам dockedItems

```
function f_create_accord(P_el_id, P_el_params) {
P_el = Ext.create
    (
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        {
            id: P_el_id

            , border: false
            , x: P_el_params.left
            , y: P_el_params.top
            , id_el: P_el_params.id_el
            , layout: 'accordion'
            , dockedItems: [{

                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',

                items: [{
                    P_el_id: P_el_id,
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'добавить',
                    
                }, {
                    id_el: P_el_id,
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'скрыть',
                    vision: true,
                    listeners: {
                        click: function (el, v2, v3) {
                            if (el.vision) {
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].setHeight(5);
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].items.items[0].hide();
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].items.items[1].setWidth(Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).getWidth());
                                el.vision = false
                            }
                            else {
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].setHeight('15px');
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].items.items[0].show();
                                Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[0].items.items[1].setWidth(60);
                                el.vision = true
                            }
                            // Ext.getCmp(el.id_el).dockedItems.items[i].hide();
                         
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }
    );

P_el.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
P_el.setStyle('box-shadow', ' 0px 0px 0px 1px green');
P_el.setStyle('background', 'border-box');
return P_el;
```

}

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).